# Can't figure out correct datastructure for table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, join

I have an application where a User can Challenge another User. A challenge has a date, a time, a place, a winner, a loser, a score it can be accepted or refused. 
I am thinking about the database structure I should apply.
At first I have created a challenge table that looks like this :

```
 create_table "challenges", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "date"
    t.time     "time"
    t.text     "place"
    t.text     "score"
    t.integer  "winner"
    t.integer  "loser"
    t.integer  "referee"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
    t.boolean  "accepted",   default: false
```

I also created a contestants join table with a user_id and a challenge_id

```
  create_table "contestants", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "challenge_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end
```

I am not sure this is the correct data structure as I now have a distinction in the views (different partials) between the creator of the challenge and the "recipient". 
Thus I now added a migration directly linking challenge to user : A challenge belongs to a user (the creator of the challenge) and a User has_many challenges. But this seems a bit redundant now with my contestants table.

What is the correct data-structure for what I want to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

You may not need the contestants table.

What about if you add two more columns to the challenge table for `challenger` and `challengee` or something of that nature?

Then a User can have_many challenges as `challenger` and also have many challenges as `challengee`.

I think you can try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

There is not redundancy and this is done all the time. Have the models emulate the terminology you use in your business domain

```
class User
  has_many :challenges  #issued challenges
  has_many :authored_challenges, dependent: :destroy, class_name: Challenge
end

class Challenge
  belongs_to :author, class_name: User, foreign_key: 'author_id'
  belongs_to :recipient, class_name: User, foreign_key: 'user_id'
end
```